# How to implement a shell function that can define a variable by pipeline?

Tags: bash, shell

```
echo 123 | func vvv
echo $vvv
```

The result is 123. How to implement it?

Comment: http://xyproblem.info/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem is that you can't set a variable with a pipeline, because each part of the pipeline runs in a separate process, and variables are local to a separate process.

However, starting in `bash` 4.2, that restriction is loosened a bit with the `lastpipe` option. This lets the *last* part of pipeline run in the same process, as long as job control is disabled. (You can do this with `set +m`, but that's only necessary in an interactive shell; job control is disabled by default in a non-interactive shell, such as in a script.)

Using this option, the command you are looking for is simply `read`:

```
$ shopt -s lastpipe
$ set +m
$ echo 123 | read vvv
$ echo "$vvv"
123
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use the [command substitution](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#Command-Substitution) provided by the shell

`$(···)`

or

```
`···`
```

Then

```
vvv=$(echo 123)
```

You don't need to define a function.